# How to correctly implement JDBC in Java classes

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class Database {
    public static java.sql.Connection createConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        final String DB_URL = "none";
        final String USER = "none";
        final String PASS = "none";

        return DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(Statement st) {
        try {
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rollback(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void getMemberID(String memberFirstName) {
        java.sql.Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = createConnection();
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            java.sql.PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Members where FNAME = ?");
            pStmt.setString(1, memberFirstName);
            ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String ID = rs.getString("MEMBER_ID");
                System.out.println("Member ID: " + ID);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I am new to JDBC and I'm trying to understand how to implement it into my program. I have a program that has Employees and Members. I want to be able to create a lot of different queries for each.

Employees and Members are both separate classes. I have made a separate class for the Database info because I saw it as an answer on here (Stack Overflow). So now I'm wondering if I am implementing it correctly. At the bottom I have made a method called getMemberID. My plan is to call this method from Database within the Members class.

Is this the correct way to implement the Database class? In my mind I would be making all of my queries in this Database class and then call the method from within whatever class I'm using (like if I wanted to get a certain employees salary I would make another method in class Database called getSalary().

Comment: try hibernate after this. It does all the heavy lifting for you and the code can be cleanly maintained

Comment: @YCF_L So even if I plan to have update statements, insert, aggregate (such as group by, sum count), joins, etc. This will work fine? I plan on having at least 30+ queries to it.

Comment: This too broad a question, and on top of that pretty much opinion-based. I suggest to read some tutorials or books on design, but I think you'll soon find there is no "one correct way".

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yea I know with programming there are multiple ways to do one thing and that there isn't a correct answer to all, but I'm just trying to find out if this way of implementing this Database class is at least achievable for what I'm trying to do (use two classes Employees and Members that will call the method e.g. getMemberID from the Database class)

Comment: Again, too broad + opinion. Search for some tutorials on DAO pattern (Data Access Object) and enterprise application design (or patterns) for some inspiration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Db Connection:

- URL_DB is in format of `jdbc:mysql://hostname:port_number/database_name`
- You need replace USER and PASS to your real ussername and password

Db Interaction:

You can use either `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` interact with the database(CRUD operations).

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
try {
   String SQL = "Update Employees SET age = ? WHERE id = ?";
   pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
   . . .
}
catch (SQLException e) {
   . . .
}
finally {
   . . .
}
```

This is just a short talking about what you need to do.  Read more JDBC tutorials online and try it yourself.

I suggest writing an interface before implementing.

```
interface DbAccess{
    Connection connect(...);
    void close(...);
    createEmployee(...);
    update(...)
    delete(...);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I'm fully connected to my database (I just left out my login info cause it is for school). I'm only concerned about the way I'm implementing my queries. Like my method getMemberID at the bottom. Do you know if this is the correct way to implement my queries?

Comment: I plan to have update statements, insert, aggregate (such as group by, sum count), joins, etc. This will work fine? I plan on having at least 30+ queries to it.

Comment: yes it will work even your code works. For all those queries you are referring to you just need proper sql statements and you are good to go.

Comment: try with resources

Comment: @XXIV it looks fine to me. my suggestion is you can write an interface(see my updates), list all the interaction methods with the outside world, and you know what is exposed.

Answer (score -1):

Good try but, no, your code is not the right way to wrap JDBC. At `getMemberID()` method you will leave a connection open on each time and soon run out of connections after a few dozens of calls.

The first thing to do when wrapping JDBC is to be sure that you are not leaking any resource.

The most straightforward way to achieve this is with a block of code like

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stm = null;
ResultSet rst = null;
try {
    con = createConnection();
    stm  = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...");
    stm.setString (1, "value1");
    rst = stm.executeQuery();
    while (rst.next()) {
       // int i = rst.getInt(1);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do whatever
} finally {
    try { if (rst!=null) rst.close(); } catch (SQLException sqle) { }
    try { if (stm!=null) stm.close(); } catch (SQLException sqle) { }
    try { if (con!=null) con.close(); } catch (SQLException sqle) { }
}
```

Next, opening a connection is a fairly slow operation, so you do not want to open a connection for each SQL statement to be execute. Therefore you´ll need a connection pool like [Apache DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) (there countless JDBC connection pool implementations to choose).

Then you need to map ResultSet values into Java variables. I personally dislike Hibernate and JPA, but that is only an opinion. If it is just for reading a writing values for a RDBMS, my personal preference is to read ResultSet into a Map and then create getter and setter method for each value.

A couple more tips: always close the resources in reverse order that you opened them, and always close a connection over which a SQLException has been raised as is highly possible that it holds and unfinished transaction that will cause any next SQL statement executed over it to fail.

Comment: But if I close all the connections after every query call, I won't run out of connections, right? If so, this code could work for the project I'm working on, right?

Comment: Why suggest this when Java has try-with-resources since Java 7.

Comment: You won't run out of connections if you close them after each call. You will run out of connections if you do not close after you are done using them.

Comment: try-with-resources is another syntactic possibility. But if using prepared statements it requires two try { } catch { } instead of one unless the prepareStatement and the parameter binding are done by a helper method. The purpose of the example was to illustrate the importance of making sure that the resources are closed after use. Not to favour one code style over another.

Answer (score -1):

This works in SQLite. I think people should move towards try with resources.

```
       String sql = "Update Employees SET age = ? WHERE id = ?"; 
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port_number/database_name");
             PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);)
        {
            ps.setString(1, age);
            ps.setString(2, id);
            ps.execute();                
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            //Catch here!
        }
```